# Why I'm getting "ERROR: Build step failed with exception..." during 'Docker Build and Publish' step in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

I'm trying to learn CI/CD with Jenkins and Docker.
I was following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/mszE-OCI2V4) and did everything same as him.

After the `maven build`, it's throwing me **Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure**.

Here's the complete log.

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.640 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-02T14:26:11+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
net.sf.json.JSONException: null object
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.verifyIsNull(JSONObject.java:2688)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.element(JSONObject.java:1733)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.element(JSONObject.java:1716)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:2328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:150)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken$1.call(DockerRegistryToken.java:125)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:46)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryToken.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryToken.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:258)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:243)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.credentials.DockerRegistryEndpoint.newKeyMaterialFactory(DockerRegistryEndpoint.java:235)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:455)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:431)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.buildAndTag(DockerBuilder.java:373)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.exec(DockerBuilder.java:311)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.access$100(DockerBuilder.java:291)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:262)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:806)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:198)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1888)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:431)
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Tried to look over the internet, but didn't get much. I didn't find anyone having the same issue.

Take a look at the docker configuration in Jenkins.
[image: Docker Configuration]

Link to the repository that I'm deploying : [Github Repository](https://github.com/i-anshuman/SpringBoot-with-jenkins-docker)

Comment: are you able to build and push the image locally without jenkins ?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to do that locally

Comment: do you the webhooks visible in git for the pipeline ?

Comment: check this, this might be missing:
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-github-repository-to-your-jenkins-project

Comment: No, I'm kept everything simple.
When I push code on github, jenkins start a new build, but it fail after maven build.
It fail when it move to docker part.

Comment: well if the build completing fine locally then its  got to do with either jenkins config or git. i'm no expert with jenkins but check the entire article posted above, it might help.

Comment: Problem is not with Git configuration.

Comment: sure, did you check the jenkins config mentioned in the article ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it's not that what I want

Comment: right your maven build and publish is failing right ? and you mentioned locally build is working fine, is that correct ?

Comment: Only publish build is failing, maven build is working fine.

Comment: you can use the config file for the pipeline to publish\push the image here:
https://dzone.com/articles/building-docker-images-to-docker-hub-using-jenkins
there is an example file for the same, just modify the info with your info for a new pipeline and try that out.

Comment: do let me know if the new config works for the publish pipeline.